# Plotly dash -- select column from uploaded csv as a dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

with plotly-dash I am able to plot a figure by selecting a column of a hard-coded csv. I have tried different examples and now I am also able to print/plot csv from an uploaded file. However, I want to upload a csv and in a dropdown menu, I want to be able to select a column and plot it.

With this I was able to plot line as well as box plot from a hard coded csv by choosing a column from a dropdown menu.

```
df = pd.read_csv('df_anomaly.csv')


    html.Div([
            html.H3([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id = 'Dropdown',
                    options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in list(df.columns.values)[1:]],
                    value='a',
                    placeholder="Name"),
            ]),

        ], className = "filter"),



    html.Div([
         html.Div([
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id='Lineplot'),
            ], style={'width': '75%','display': 'inline-block', 'marginLeft': '15', 'marginTop': '15'}),

            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id='Boxplot')
            ], style={'width': '23.8%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'marginRight': '15','marginTop': '15','float':'right'})], style={
             'padding': '10px 15px'
         }),

    ], style={'padding': '5px 0px','backgroundColor': colors['grey'], 'marginTop': '8', 'marginBottom': '8'})

    ])

# Updating Observed Data Plot
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('Lineplot', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Dropdown', 'value')])

def update_graph(selector):
    df_selected = init_calc(selector)

    return {
        'data': [go.Scatter(
            y = np.array(df_selected['selected']),
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(
                color = colors['red']
            )
        )],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            height=400,
            title=go.layout.Title(
                text='Line Plot',
                font=dict(
                    color = colors['black'],
                )
            ),
            xaxis=dict(
                title='x',
                linecolor = colors['black'],
                color = colors['black'],
                ticks='inside',
                zeroline = False,
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title='y',
                linecolor = colors['black'],
                color = colors['black'],
                ticks='inside',
                zeroline = False,
            ),
            hovermode='closest',
        )
    }

# Updating Boxplot
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('Boxplot', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Dropdown', 'value')])

def update_boxplot(selector):

    df_selected = init_calc(selector)

    return {
        'data': [go.Box(
            name='',
            y=df_selected['selected'],
            marker = dict(
                color = colors['orange']
            )
        )],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            height=400,
            title=go.layout.Title(
                text='Boxplot', 
                font=dict(
                    color = colors['black'],
                )
            ),
            xaxis=dict(
                linecolor = colors['black'],
                color = colors['black'],
                zeroline = False,
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title='Traffic',
                linecolor = colors['black'],
                color = colors['black'],
                zeroline = False,
                ticks='inside',
            ),
        ),
    }

def init_calc(selector):
    df_selected = pd.DataFrame(columns=['selected'])
    df_selected['selected'] = df[str(selector)]
    return df_selected

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Running the App
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Also, If I add this bit of code I can print the uploaded csv:

```
html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '2px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
]),

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
#         html.H6(datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=df[:5].to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
#         html.Div('Raw Content'),
#         html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
#             'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
#             'wordBreak': 'break-all'
#         })
    ])


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename'),
               State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
```

with the little tweak I can also manually choose the column and plot the column of the uploaded csv but I want to be able to select a column of uploaded csv as I did with the hardcoded one. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered start to play from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224376/4819376)?

Comment: @rpanai Yes indeed, I am able to create a graph from an uploaded csv, However, I am not able to filter the columns of the csv from the dropdown and only plot that column.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `parse_contents` return also the `df` apart from the html piece for displaying the content. Call it say `df_uploaded`.

And then where you have the html content for the dropdown, replace your df with this df_uploaded like so:

```
html.Div([
        html.H3([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'Dropdown',
                options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in list(df_uploaded.columns.values)[1:]],
                value='a',
                placeholder="Name"),
        ]),

    ], className = "filter"),
```

Usually what I do is to seperate out all graph generating functions in a separate .py file say data_and_graphs.py. Here I would typically have functions which return figure objects example:

```
def generate_line_graph(x,y):
      l_grf = go.Fig()
      #add_trace()
      #add_layout()
      return l_grf
```

And then in the layout i simply `import data_and_graphs.py as grf` 
Where there is a reference to the graph, i would put it as

```
dcc.Graph(
   id='graph1',
   figure=grf.l_grf
)
```

On the same lines, I would then reference the df columns in the drop down by calling `options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in list(grf.df_uploaded_cols)]`
where you can simply put relevant columns in a list assigned to `df_uploaded_cols`

Hope this gives some pointers for tweaking your code to get columns of uploaded csv.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I return `df` from the function `parse_content` I get  `TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable`.  Also by simply replacing `df` by `df_uploaded` in the content for dropdown surely gives `name not defined` error?

Comment: You have to return df from parse_content outside of the html component that you are already returning. The idea was to give you pointers and inspiration on how to tweak your code to make it work as per your requirements.  df_uploaded has to be captured from the callback, depending on what the user has uploaded etc.